# Ion nav view not working properly

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

So In the Ionic I am using ui-router with nav view but it doesn't seem to work properly:

app.js

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })
.state('app.book', {
    url: '/book',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/book.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.service', {
    url: '/service',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/service.html',
        controller: 'ServiceController'
      }
    }
  })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/book');
```

home.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">

        <button class="button icon-left ion-navicon-round button-clear " menu-toggle="left"> </button>

        <h1 class="title">Maalish</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>//Nav View
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>

      <ion-item item-icon-left menu-close href="#/app/splash">
         <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
          &nbsp Home
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Book.html

```
<ion-view view-title="book">
<ion-content class="book-content">
  Hi
<a href="#/app/service">Click </a>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Service.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="service">
    <ion-content class="book-content">
      Hey

    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

So here is the small description:

Home.html-It has the sidemenu required on all the pages/screens its the parent screen

Book.html:Its the deafault and first screen link to service.html

Service.html:Its the second screen.

**Problem:**
So when I open the app the book.html opens and it has the sidemenu(home.html) but when i click on the link service.html The page opens but it doesnt have sidemenu.If i refresh the link of service.html only then the sidemenu opens.
Sidemenu doesn't appear when redirected from book.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It you just have to change  to  I.e change true to false